# Upload folder using Terraforms file provisioner

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am using ECS to run some containers, I need to load a directory that holds some config into one of the containers. With docker compose I can do the following to mount the directory into the container from my host machine.

```
  go-1:
    image: link to my ecr repo here
    command: run -c /app/node/
    volumes:
      - ./go/nodes/node_0:/app/node
```

I want to do something similar with Terraform and upload the nodes_0 directory into my container from my host machine, my current approach is to use the file provisioner like so:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app" {
  family = var.app_task_family
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = [
    "FARGATE",
  ]
  cpu = var.fargate_cpu
  memory = var.fargate_memory
  container_definitions = data.template_file.app.rendered

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "../go/nodes/node_0"
    destination = "/app/node"
  }
}
```

However this gives me the following error when I run Terraform apply:

```
Error: timeout - last error: dial tcp :22: connect: connection refused
```

My ECS cluster sits in a private subnet so I'm thinking this might be the issue.

Is there a better way to upload a folder into my container running on ECS?

Answer (score -1):

As you suggested the

> My ECS cluster sits in a private subnet so I'm thinking this might be
> the issue.

Yes since it's in a private subnet you need to either ensure that the server or PC that runs terraform codes are in the same subnet or you can do a VPC peering and make sure there are routes btw both subnets.

If you use a version control system like git you can do a git clone from the repository to the instance but you also need to make sure the instance has a nat gateway enabled.

Then you need to mount the folder after you have cloned the repository to your instance like this.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app" {
  family             = var.app_task_family
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  network_mode       = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = [
    "FARGATE",
  ]
  cpu                   = var.fargate_cpu
  memory                = var.fargate_memory
  container_definitions = data.template_file.app.rendered

  volume {
    name      = "node-storage"
    host_path = "/home/user_name_replaced/go/nodes/node_0" #You declare the host path here
  }

}
```

Your data.template_file.app.rendered

```
[
  {
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
          {
              "hostPort": 80,
              "containerPort": 80,
              "protocol": "tcp"
          }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
          {
              "containerPath": "/your_path_/",
              "sourceVolume": "node-storage" #the host folder gets mounted to the container path
          }
      ],
      "name": "your_image",
      "image": "your_image"
  }
]
```